# Cannot connect to any bluetooth hardware,

Tags: bluetooth, hardware

[Bluetooth Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rInhj.png)
My laptop does not pickup any bluetooth hardware. What do I do?

Comment: What desktop do you use ? What bluetooth manager ?

Comment: It's the default bluetooth manager for ubuntu 16.04 LTS, i have installed a macUbuntu theme, that's why it looks different.

Comment: Bluetooth support on Ubuntu is flakey at best. That said, I went to great lengths to get mine working on Ubuntu MATE 16.04, it involved setting up with command line tools. Wasnt trivial but works well once set up. I will dig out my notes when I am back in the office next week. Meanwhile, have a look at usimg the bluez command line tools to search for and pair with devices.

Comment: It also occurs to me, do you need firmware for your BT adapter ? At the command line type 'dmesg' and look for the section showing your BT adapter, does this give any info ?

Comment: I got a huge response when I typed 'dmesg' , so, instead, i tried : dmesg | grep bluetooth, 
over here , i got 3 lines in response, in which all 3 shows : Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2

Comment: So it looks like you dont have the right firmware. Firmware lives in /lib/firmware, so have a hunt around the net for your firmware and put the binary blob in there and try again.